# Not getting option to install next to windows during installation process

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Windows 8 installed on a new computer and want Ubuntu 14 installed next to it. I used UNetBootin to make a Ubuntu usb stick and rebooted from that. During the installation process however I don't get the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows like I used to. I've done this several times before and know that option is usually there even when no partition is prepared for Ubuntu. What could be the reason for the installer not showing this?

p.s. I installed Windows myself on this pc and know there is only 1 primary partition and no hidden ones or anything.
p.p.s. Windows 8 is installed through UEFI, and as I've read this might be the problem?

Comment: You probably didn't shrink your Windows partition to make room.